# EditText not editable on real device

Tags: android, android-edittext

EditText is editable on emulator, but not in my LG G2 and other real devices. But in the other activity it is editable, but not this one. I have no idea, how to solve this problem.

**Here is my xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:hint="Search for a group..."
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >-->
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using RelativeLayout. So you need to position the views relative to some other view.

Remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from ListView and add `android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"`

Comment: Works. Thank you! :)